# Large PHP Arrays pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have an array that has over 10k results (generated by a MySQL query) and I wonder what is the best practice for paginate it? Extract all the data first then split it to pages or there is another faster/best way?

Comment: You can do this in conjuction with MySQLs `limit` and `offset` methods.

Comment: see this basic paging article  http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination

Answer (score 5):

Use MySQL's [`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) syntax to only retrieve the desired results from the database before it even reaches your PHP code.

Something like this:

```
$offset = 0;
$per_page = 25;

$query = "SELECT * FROM `blah` LIMIT $offset, $per_page";

...
```

Answer (score 3):

As suggested, you can use `LIMIT`. To find out the total number of results, you can optionally do:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM `table` ... LIMIT 0, 20
```

Then:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS `total_results`
```

To retrieve your paginator's maximum page number.

Comment: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/

It says using COUNT and SELECT again with limit is faster.

Answer (score 1):

To *display* the pagination navigation links for this many records, consider using "logarithmic" page navigation. See here:

[How to do page navigation for many, many pages? Logarithmic page navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7835752/999120)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to do a COUNT() query before pulling your content to determine how many rows you have in total. The general algortihm for finding out how many pages you need is then

> ceil( totalRows / rowsPerPage )