# Limit with offset ("LIMIT 500000, 10") is slow even after index?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, limit

I've got a table with `int` field, let's call it `createTime`. The table consists of few million records. Now I want to run the query:

```
select * from `table` order by `createTime` desc limit 500000, 10
```

I've created an index for `createTime`, but the query runs INCREDIBLY slow. What's the reason? How can I improve it?

Here's what EXPLAIN says:

```
id 1
select_type simple
table table
type index
possible_keys null
key createTime
key_len 4
ref null
rows 500010
extra
```

As for the offset, it's working much faster when it's small.

Comment: Have you tried using the EXPLAIN keyword to see what MySql is doing? Effectively, EXPLAIN select * from `table` order by `createTime` desc limit 500000, 10. Out of interest, what data type is createTime?

Comment: I've explained in the question it's an int. EXPLAIN says nothing interesting, it's using the created index and it estimates the number of rows to 500010.

Comment: (What was the performance like *before* the index was created? What about a limit with no offset? A limit with a smaller offset?)

Comment: @SebastianNowak: Why not _show_ us what `EXPLAIN` says? Since you're asking for alternative interpretations of the data...

Comment: Sorry, I meant what does a typical createTime column contain - a few example values. Also, are you using ISAM, InnoDB?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does MYSQL higher LIMIT offset slow the query down?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481388/why-does-mysql-higher-limit-offset-slow-the-query-down)

Comment: Does it make a difference if you write `select "createTime" from "table" order by "createTime" desc limit 500000, 10`? (Sorry, I don't know how to embed backticks in comments.)

Comment: It's MyISAM, and createTime contains the result of time() function in PHP - so time in seconds since 1970. I've updated the question to provide more details.

Comment: @Neil: `With a \`Backslash\`?` Same as in non-comment posts.

Comment: @Neil: It does, now the query takes few seconds to run

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Ah, I read the markdown help but didn't see that, thanks!

Comment: check out my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942742/large-php-arrays-pagination/4943129#4943129

Answer (score 9, accepted):

General rule: [avoid `OFFSET` for large tables](http://www.4pmp.com/2010/02/scalable-mysql-avoid-offset-for-large-tables/).

> [A]s the offset increases, the time taken for the query to execute
>   progressively increases, which can mean processing very large tables
>   will take an extremely long time. The reason is because offset works
>   on the physical position of rows in the table which is not indexed. So
>   to find a row at offset x, the database engine must iterate through
>   all the rows from 0 to x.

> The general rule of thumb is “never use offset in a limit clause”. For
>   small tables you probably won’t notice any difference, but with tables
>   with over a million rows you’re going to see huge performance
>   increases.

Comment: I would prefer *"avoid large OFFSET"*

Comment: @ypercube: But large `OFFSET` for small tables is fine.

Comment: You mean when OFFSET is larger than the table size? Yeah, I guess so. Pointless but fine.

Comment: My (perhaps overly touchy) comment was because I find the title of that article slightly misleading. Using small offsets with proper index in large tables can be ok. (and the text below agrees)

Comment: @ypercube: My (typically wittily retort-like) comment happily glossed over the notion that you're not wrong. :)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: what would you use instead of OFFSET or OFFSET in LIMIT?

Answer (score 2):

You can speed this up if you have a unique column. Ideally it would be createTime itself:

```
SELECT "table".*
  FROM "table"
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT "createTime"
      FROM "table"
      ORDER BY "createTime" DESC
      LIMIT 500000, 10
  ) AS "limit" ON "table"."createTime" = "limit"."createTime"
```

If createTime is not unique, but you have another column that is unique, then you may find you need to create a composite index on createTime and your other column in order for this query to run efficiently:

```
SELECT "table".*
  FROM "table"
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT "createTime", "unique"
      FROM "table"
      ORDER BY "createTime" DESC
      LIMIT 500000, 10
  ) AS "limit" ON "table"."unique" = "limit"."unique"
```

Comment: Thanks, but this query still takes few seconds to run. It's unacceptable as for a website. Isn't there any faster way to implement pagination basing on createTime column?

Answer (score 0):

I think indexing won't change anything. Using `offset, limit` means "read offset + limit datasets and discard (num of offset) of them". If you really want have a pagination or something like that for such a large table, you should use a method where you can limit your results in the WHERE part of your query. Those type of query will benefit of a proper index.

Using datetimes, a solution might be to use timeslots to display your data. E.g. you can display links for each day of a week and build your query like "WHERE createDate > '2011-12-11' AND crateDate < '2011-12-12'.